# Using noparse option of browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify, onsen-ui

I'm having issues including a third party library that does not need to be parsed by browserify using the noparse option.

Doing the following results in an error (provided below)

```
$> npm install onsenui@2.0.0-alpha.6
$> npm install browserify
$> echo "onsenui = require('onsenui/js/onsenui');" > index.js
$> node_modules/.bin/browserify --noparse="onsenui/js/onsenui" index.js > build.js
```

Results in the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module './core.js' from '/Users/user/browsify-test/node_modules/onsenui/js'
    at /Users/user/browsify-test/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
    at load (/Users/user/browsify-test/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/Users/user/browsify-test/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /Users/user/browsify-test/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
```

I would expect browserify would not try to follow requires in the onsenui file because it has already been bundled for consumption, and I told browserify not to parse the requires.